# How to Add a Drop Down List in a Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

Using Kendo UI and a Row Template, I have a grid started like the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/xF4CK/

I'm wanting to alter the Actions column to contain a drop down list populated by the actions object.  The actions object contains display text and a relative url path like the following example:

```
var actions = [
    { name: "edit", url: "reports/report/1" },
    { name: "delete", url: "reports/delete/1" }
];
```

This actions object is on each row of the grid and may vary per row/user/etc. The intended usage would be a user selects the drop down list and then chooses one of the options.  On choosing the option the url value is posted.

I'm not sure where to begin, or if it is possible in the Row Template.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it figured out. In the row template I am calling a js function and returning  html markup for the list. Then setting the .kendoDropDownList on all items based on a class attribute.  I have updated the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xF4CK/1/) but it doesn't seem to work in jsfiddle.  It is working when I test in IE10 and Chrome on my dev machine.

**Here's the relevant code changes:**

In the rowTemplate, changed

```
#: actions #
```

to

```
#= renderDropDown(actions) #
```

This "=" displays the literal text which renders the html as html whereas the ":" encodes the html.

The renderDropDown function:

```
function renderDropDown(actions) {
    var dropDownList = "<select class=\"insight-dropdown\">";

    dropDownList = dropDownList + "<option value=\"default\" disable=\"disabled\">...</option>";

    for (var i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
        dropDownList = dropDownList + "<option value=\"" + actions[i].url + "\">" + actions[i].name + "</option>";
    }

    dropDownList = dropDownList + "</select>";
    return dropDownList;
}
```

To the dataBound event of the grid, I added this function to turn the html into a drop down list:

```
// Set the drop down lists
$(".insight-dropdown").kendoDropDownList({
    select: onDDLSelect
});
```

To handle the selection of an action:

```
function onDDLSelect(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
    alert(dataItem.value);
}
```